# complete.case() remove NA in R

Tags: r, dataframe, na, remove-if

I have 8 columns in a data set.  Some or all have NA.  I want to remove all rows if any column has an NA.  What i find is happening is that my code removes the rows if there is an NA in the first column but not any of the others.

`rawdata` is the data frame that has `NA`'s.  `GoodData` is suppose to be the new data frame with the NA removed.

```
GoodData <- rawdata[complete.cases(rawdata),]
```

Comment: Perhaps the `NA` in other columns are `"NA"` characters.

Comment: It does not look that way.  It doesn't work so I have no idea

Comment: @Pirates_say_R Can you paste the output of `dput(droplevels(head(rawdata)))`